# How to generate Supercut of video in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to generate supercut of video max duration 30 seconds. I am new to laravel could anyone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not provide any built in functionality to achieve video manipulating. So using a third party is required.

[PHP-FFMPEG](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) library is a video/audio library. It does many common video-editing tools including taking shots of particular frame(s).

notice that you need to have FFMpeg binary on your machine as [documentation](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg#how-this-library-works) sais:

> This library requires a working FFMpeg install. You will need both FFMpeg and FFProbe binaries to use it. Be sure that these binaries can be located with system PATH to get the benefit of the binary detection, otherwise you should have to explicitly give the binaries path on load.

after configuration completed you can [take frame shots](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg#extracting-image) easily:

```php
$video
    ->filters()
    ->extractMultipleFrames(FFMpeg\Filters\Video\ExtractMultipleFramesFilter::FRAMERATE_EVERY_10SEC, '/path/to/destination/folder/')
    ->synchronize();

$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), '/path/to/new/file');
```

Good Luck